# Whitelist Author of Private Post

Tags: posts, author, private

Does anyone know of a way to whitelist the author of a private post so they never have to enter their password to access their own post on the frontend? If they are logged into the site, there must be a way to remove the requirement to enter the password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_password_required` filter.

```
function wpse406803_whitelist_author( $required, $post ) {
    
    //Check if current user is the post author
    if ( $post->post_author == get_current_user_id() ) {
        return false;
    }
    
}
add_filter( 'post_password_required', 'wpse406803_whitelist_author', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Your solution makes total sense but for some reason it removes the password protection for all users, not just the post author. Could it be because I am using custom post types?

Comment: @AaronWimberley That can happen if the $post parameter isn't available. Try adding `global $post;` just before the author ID check.

Comment: I updated it to this:
`add_filter( 'post_password_required', 'whitelist_author', 10, 2 );
function whitelist_author( $required, $post ) {
    global $post;
    //Check if current user is the post author
 if ( $post->post_author == get_current_user_id() ) {
        return false;
    }
    
}`

But no luck.

Comment: What happens when you `var_dump` the `$post` object? Also, try printing `get_current_user_id()`  and see if they match.

Comment: Still no luck... It doesn't make sense that it is not working. It is reading the current user and the author ID correctly.